# Socket Bluetooth Windows - Can't connect to device:(10049)

Tags: windows, socket, bluetooth, delphi-10, porta-serial

Estou tendo problemas de erro de soquete com código 10049 quando tento conectar um dispositivo SSP bluetooth, serviço de porta serial, em Delphi Tokyo 10.2 no ambiente Windows utilizando uma classe TBluetoothSocket. O erro ocorre no momento da conexão (TBluetoothSocket.Connect), erro ocorre na linha 152 da unit Main abaixo, segue:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, System.Bluetooth,
  System.Bluetooth.Components, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Edit,
  FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base,
  FMX.ListView;

type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    ButtonDiscoverDevices: TButton;
    Bluetooth: TBluetooth;
    ListBoxDevices: TListBox;
    ListBoxServices: TListBox;
    ButtonOpenClose: TButton;
    Edit: TEdit;
    Panel: TPanel;
    ButtonSend: TButton;
    Timer: TTimer;
    ListView1: TListView;
    AniIndicator1: TAniIndicator;
    procedure ButtonDiscoverDevicesClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BluetoothDiscoveryEnd(const Sender: TObject;
      const ADeviceList: TBluetoothDeviceList);
    procedure ButtonOpenCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonSendClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListBoxDevicesChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    DeviceList: TBluetoothDeviceList;
    Device: TBluetoothDevice;
    SerialPort: TBluetoothService;
    Socket: TBluetoothSocket;
    Connected: Boolean;
    procedure ShowWaitIndicator;
    procedure HideWaitIndicator;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFormMain.ShowWaitIndicator;
begin
  AniIndicator1.Enabled := True;
  AniIndicator1.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TFormMain.HideWaitIndicator;
begin
  AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
  AniIndicator1.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TFormMain.ButtonDiscoverDevicesClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SerialPort.Name := '';
  Device := nil;
  DeviceList := nil;
  ButtonOpenClose.Enabled := False;
  ListBoxDevices.Clear;
  ListBoxServices.Clear;

  Bluetooth.DiscoverDevices(45000); // 45s
  ShowWaitIndicator;
end;

procedure TFormMain.BluetoothDiscoveryEnd(const Sender: TObject; const ADeviceList: TBluetoothDeviceList);
var I: Integer;
begin
  HideWaitIndicator;
  ListBoxDevices.Clear;
  for I := 0 to ADeviceList.Count - 1 do
    ListBoxDevices.Items.Add(ADeviceList.Items[I].DeviceName);
  DeviceList := ADeviceList;
end;

procedure TFormMain.ListBoxDevicesChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  DeviceIndex: Integer;
  LastServices: TBluetoothServiceList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SerialPort.Name := '';
  ListBoxServices.Clear;
  ButtonOpenClose.Enabled := False;
  DeviceIndex := ListBoxDevices.ItemIndex;
  if DeviceIndex = -1 then
    Exit;

  /// Recuperar o dispositivo selecionado
  Device := nil;
  if DeviceList <> nil then
    if (DeviceIndex >= 0) and (DeviceIndex < DeviceList.Count) then
      Device := DeviceList.Items[DeviceIndex];
  if Device = nil then
    Exit;

  ShowWaitIndicator;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  try
    /// Parear dispositivo
    if not Device.IsPaired then
      if not Bluetooth.Pair(Device) or not Device.IsPaired then
      begin
        ListBoxDevices.ItemIndex := -1;
        raise Exception.Create('Device ''' + Device.DeviceName + ''' is not paired');
      end;

    /// Pesquisar pelo serviço de serial port
    LastServices := Device.LastServiceList;
    ListBoxServices.Clear;
    for I := 0 to LastServices.Count - 1 do
    begin
      ListBoxServices.Items.Add(LastServices[I].Name);
      if LastServices[I].Name = 'SerialPort' then
        SerialPort := LastServices[I];
    end;
    if SerialPort.Name = '' then
      raise Exception.Create('SerialPort service not found');

    ButtonOpenClose.Enabled := True;
  finally
    HideWaitIndicator;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.ButtonOpenCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Connected then
  begin
    Connected := False;
    try
      Socket.Close;
    except
    end;
    Socket := nil;
  end
  else
  begin
    Socket := Device.CreateClientSocket(SerialPort.UUID, True);
    Socket.Connect;
    Connected := Socket.Connected;
  end;

  if Connected then
  begin
    ButtonOpenClose.Text := 'Close';
    ButtonDiscoverDevices.Enabled := False;
    ListBoxDevices.Enabled := False;
    Edit.Enabled := True;
    ButtonSend.Enabled := True;
    Timer.Enabled := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    ButtonOpenClose.Text := 'Open';
    ButtonDiscoverDevices.Enabled := True;
    ListBoxDevices.Enabled := True;
    Edit.Enabled := False;
    ButtonSend.Enabled := False;
    Timer.Enabled := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.ButtonSendClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Socket.SendData(TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(Edit.Text));
end;

procedure TFormMain.TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: TBytes;
  ItemList: TListViewItem;
begin
  Data := Socket.ReceiveData(0);
  if Data <> nil then
  begin
    ItemList := ListView1.Items.Add;
    ItemList.Text := TEncoding.ANSI.GetString(Data);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: 10049 means that device does not support service you are tring to connect to.

Comment: Em modo debbug vá até essa linha (151) `Socket := Device.CreateClientSocket(SerialPort.UUID, True);` e verifique se o `SerialPort.UUID` possui algum dado

Comment: Olá Matheus Ribeiro, sim consta o GUID de comunicação com serial port, -> '{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}'

Comment: Mike Petrichenko, Yes the service is supported by the device, because with the same example for Android works, it connects normally.